# Pattern matching on case classes with * (varargs) parameter

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have two case class like:

```
case class B(value:Int)
case class A(a:String, b:B*) extends ALike
```

and I want to do pattern match on an instance of A:

```
def foo(al:ALike) = {
  al match {
    case A(a, bs) => ...
  }
}
```

Scalac doesn't understand that `bs` is a `Seq[B]` and thinks that it is just one `B`. Why is that the case and how should I do pattern match on it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a varargs argument, so you need to explain that to the compiler explicitly. Use the following case expression:

```
def foo(al:ALike) = {
  al match {
    case A(a, bs @ _*) => ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way to define type for `bs`. its `Seq[Any]` by default

Comment: @ChitralVerma `bs` in the example above should be a sequence with the same inner type that you defined for the field when defining the enclosing case class. I.e. in this case, its type should be `Seq[B]`. Perhaps you can open a new question describing your exact example.